# Why is the variable inside this function global?

Tags: javascript, scope

I thought any variable defined in a function would be local but I can easily access variable 'e' outside of its function.

```
function change() {
 var d = 6; 
  e = 7;
}

change();
alert(e); //> alerts 7
```

Comment: Did you intend to put a comma after `var d = 6`? Reason why I ask is because of the extra indentation on `e` which is typical when defining multiple variables (on multiple lines) in a single var statement. If you replaced the semicolon with a comma, `e` would be a local variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because new variables will enter the global scope by default.  `var` prevents this from happening by constraining a variable's existence to be within the current scope.

Comment: Except when you're in strict mode when you throw ReferenceError when you hit an undeclared variable.

Comment: @user701092 then you were taught by the wrong person, or you misunderstood.  (Possibly you were told to only use `var` once **per variable** per scope.)

Comment: @user That suggestion, AFAIK, is from Douglas Crockford and his [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/). To apply `var` to multiple declarations, use a comma to separate them: `var d = 6, e = 7;`

Comment: JSLint suggests a lot of nonsensical things.  I suggest ignoring those suggestions.

Comment: @Pointy does that mean I have to define every single variable with 'var' and not without??

Comment: @user701092 yes, that is what that means, **unless** you know you explicitly want to refer to a variable in an outer scope.

Answer (score 2):

Because it was declared without `var` it becomes part of the global `window` object.

Answer (score 1):

You've not explicitly declared it as such, so it has taken global scope.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because e is global by default, using var make a scope varible.
You can read more about this in [Javascript Garden Scope and Namespaces](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are going under this assumption that

> JSLint expects that a var will be
>   declared only once, and that it will
>   be declared before it is used.

Problem with your code is you are using one var, but your second line has no var in front of it. That is pushing that varaible e into the global namespace.

Why is it happening? You used a semicolon instead of a comma in the variable declaration.

```
function change() {
 var d = 6, //Change this to a comma 
     e = 7;
}

change();
alert(e); //will produce an error now
```

Answer (score 1):

It is surprisingly easy to create global variables, here are some other gotchas I've seen.

```
// :-( antipattern: implied global variable
function sum(x, y) {
    result = x + y; // result is global
    return result;
}

// :-) better
function sum(x, y) {
    var result = x + y; // result is local
    return result;
}

// :-( antipattern: chain assignments as part of a var declaration
function foo() {
    var a = b = 0; // b is global
}

// :-) better
function foo() {
    var a, b;
    a = b = 0; // both local
}
```